# A file I was using for org-capture has been renamed (*filename*.org -> *filename* (1).org, is this normal?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, filenames

I wanted to rule out this being a feature of org-capture, maybe a result of manually editing the file or something?

If anyone has any other suggestions as to what else could have caused it I would be very appreciative.

The org-capture template was just an empty todo bullet under a heading, I added some bullets which were not TODO's to the end of the file recently. I don't know when exactly the file rename occured.

Edit:
I should clarify that upon creating a new capture it created a new file *filename*.org. No new captures are stored in *filename* (1).org

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE! I don't believe emacs creates backups that look like this (see also option `version-control`) – at least not out-of-the-box. Are you sure this isn't your operating system attempting to be 'helpful'? (FWIW, no, I've never seen this behavior in 10+ years of Org use.)